# Errors not displayed in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, apache2

My setup:

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep 12 2012 18:59:41) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans

Zend Framework 1.11.1
PHP 5.3.4
php.ini:
   error_reporting E_ALL | E_STRICT
    display_errors On
    display_startup_errors On
```

I have also enabled error logging to file (file is empty),
and turned on `xdebug.scream`.

But in some cases errors are not displayed, I get empty page instead (e.g. parse errors in some classes (missing semicolon) or using not existing interfaces).

Looks like I get very similar issue to this old one: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2463

Debugger won't start in such case, hard to guess where the error actually occurs.
Setting custom error handler does not help too, and changing settings of autoloader to suppress not found warrings as well.

Any other options how to force ZF to always display the error messages?

### Edit:

`application.ini` settings are set up properly too

Answer (score 0):

You should add :

```
define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'development');
```

in index.php, the opposite being :

```
define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'production');
```

Then in application.ini :

```
[production : bootstrap]

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors         = 0
settings.debug.enabled             = false

[qa : production]

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors         = 0
settings.debug.enabled             = false

[preqa : qa]

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors         = 0
settings.debug.enabled             = false

[testing : preqa]

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors         = 1
settings.debug.enabled             = false

[development : testing]

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors         = 1
settings.debug.enabled             = true
```

Or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is also in application.ini

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

These will overide whatever you set in php.ini or index.php.